# LINQ function anonymous type not exist in current context

Tags: linq, lambda, anonymous

I have recently inherited my company's sometimes buggy websites, but not the code that goes with them so am decompiling the binaries using ilspy. An error that I cam getting is in the following:

```
decimal? locA = (from x in data where x.location == (int?)0 && 
x.invoice.Year  == (int?)year && x.invoice.Month == (int?)month
select x).Sum((<>f__AnonymousType1<Invoice, int?> x) => x.invoice.Month_Value);
```

The problem is in the line `<>f__AnonymousType1<Invoice, int?>`. The error message (design time) is that the type `f__AnonymousType1` does not exist in the current context. (The code has decompiled to have 15 of these) A cannot find anywhere where `f__AnonymousType1` is declared.

Thanks for any help with this...

Gareth

Comment: These are anonymous types. What are to trying to do?

Comment: There is no documentation with the sites and all the developers left some time ago, so I am trying to interpret the sites as I go along. That snippet is from a function called 'GuageDataForMonth'. An invoice table broken down by month and region. It is trying to sum invoices by month. As there is not original code, I was wondering is those anonymous type are the result of the decompiler 'guessing'. The resultant class to be returned is single record agregated table data

Comment: Your decompiler looks bad, normally such patterns are decompiled better. I use Reflector which I think handles all C# patterns. Your only goal is to understand?

Comment: No. It is in production but other areas need to be changed for example hard-coded email addresses for invoices, sales data etc..

Comment: Reflector can decompile an entire assembly to a C# project. I would try that first.

Comment: Will have a look. I started looking at it before, but moved away. I will give it more time... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it is a lambda expression (anonymous function?) taking a type of `Invoice` and expects a return type of `int?`. It's declared right there. Just remove it.  The compiler typically auto generates that for you.

`.Sum((<>f__AnonymousType1<Invoice, int?> x) => x.invoice.Month_Value)` becomes `.Sum((x)=>x.invoice.Month_Value)` or `.Sum(x=>x.invoice.Month_Value)`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply... Got called away to another office for a few days . Thanks for that reply. I got Reflector 9 down (I already had 8 having tried before)   and made the changes but unfortunately, could not try the change as another area failed to decompile.